# Using GetHashCode to identify clients socket

Tags: sockets, lazarus, freepascal

Im using lNet. I found in every received socket GetHashCode function. Every socket from each user has own HashCode.

I would like to use this HashCode to identify sockets from each client.

Can I use this function to identify clients sockets?

for ex.

```
pseudocode

//after OnAccept and log in
//OnReceive
if user = SomeDictionary.Find(aSocket.GetHashCode)
write( Msg from user: user.UserName )
```

Comment: Different objects can have the same hash code.

Comment: I know that can be a collision but in this case is high risk that a few clients will have the same hash code?

Comment: If you don't mind your program failing sometimes, then go ahead

Comment: My problem is: Client log in, client has unique id. When he log out then send to server info with id. When client for ex kill proces then he will not send info with id. Server receive only aSocket (lNet component) on OnDisconnect method. Now I must find proper Client based on this socket and take appropriate log out by server side.

Comment: That's not what you asked. You asked if `GetHashCode` would identify your sockets.